# Javascript Get Yesterdays Day of Week

Tags: javascript

I have a string that contains a day of the week (ex "Monday"). I need to figure out how to take this string and get the previous day of the week.

For example if the string contains "Monday" the new string should output "Sunday".

I feel like there is a simple solution (that isn't 7 IF statements) that I'm missing here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```js
let yesterday = {
  'Monday': 'Sunday',
  'Tuesday': 'Monday',
  'Wednesday': 'Tuesday',
  'Thursday': 'Wednesday',
  'Friday': 'Thursday',
  'Saturday': 'Friday',
  'Sunday': 'Saturday',
}

console.log(yesterday['Monday']);
```

Comment: This should be the best performing answer I think

Comment: Accepted this as answer since it's much easier to read and understand. Have to think of future developers so they don't hunt me down! https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bnt1ZZjIUAAYgLZ.jpg

Answer (score 6):

One straightforward approach, *assuming correct input*, would be using arrays:

```
days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
previousDay = days[(days.indexOf(currentDay)-1+7)%7];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indexOf` and return `Sun` when you exceed array range:

```js
let currentDay = "Mon";

let days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
let prevDay = days[days.indexOf(currentDay) - 1 ] || "Sun";

console.log(prevDay);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a lot of if statements, just a function that uses `array.length` and `array.indexOf()`:

```js
let daysOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];

let yesterday = (today) => {
   if(daysOfWeek.indexOf(today) === 0){
      return daysOfWeek[daysOfWeek.length - 1];
   }else{
      return daysOfWeek[daysOfWeek.indexOf(today) - 1];
   }
}

console.log(yesterday("Sunday"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solutions could look as follows

```js
const daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const index = daysOfWeek.indexOf('Monday');
console.log(index ? daysOfWeek[index - 1] : daysOfWeek[6]);
```

You just find a position of the current day and take the previous one in the array. The only check you should make for the `index === 0` because negative indexes do not return elements from the end of the array in JavaScript